# How to retrieve image from firestore in a clickable span widget?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully uploaded the media in the firebase but i'm unable to retrieve it. apparently it shows that the media_problem is pointing to a null object. below is my code.

This is my code to retrieve:

```
 this.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Dash_agri.this.getApplicationContext(), "TOO FAST! TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            try {
                Dash_agri.this.firestore.collection("problems").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    public void onComplete( Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Dash_agri.this.records.clear();
                            Iterator it = ((QuerySnapshot) task.getResult()).iterator();
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                QueryDocumentSnapshot document = (QueryDocumentSnapshot) it.next();
                                Dash_agri.this.single_ID = document.getId();
                                Dash_agri.this.single_name = (String) document.get("NAME_problems");
                                Dash_agri.this.single_phone = (String) document.get("PHONE_problems");
                                Dash_agri.this.single_description = (String) document.get("DESCRIPTION_problems");
                                Dash_agri.this.single_URL = (String) document.get("MEDIA_problems");
                                String view_media = "Touch to view media";
                                new SpannableString(view_media).setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Dash_agri.this.getApplicationContext(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }, 0, 9, 33);
                                Dash_agri.this.record_id.add(Dash_agri.this.single_ID);
                                ArrayList<String> arrayList = Dash_agri.this.records;
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                sb.append("QUERY#");
                                sb.append(Dash_agri.this.single_ID);
                                sb.append(" by ");
                                sb.append(Dash_agri.this.single_name);
                                sb.append("\n");
                                sb.append(Dash_agri.this.single_description);
                                sb.append("\n\n");
                                sb.append(view_media);
                                arrayList.add(sb.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Dash_agri.this.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            Dash_agri.this.listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Dash_agri.this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Dash_agri.this.records));
        }
    });
```

This is my code to upload:

```
public class Upload extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST = 1;
String MEDIA_url;
String NAME;
String PHONE;
long TIME_ID = System.currentTimeMillis();
String USER_ID;
TextView file;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
Button img;
EditText prob;
ProgressBar progressBar;
StorageReference storageReference;
Button upld;
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public Uri uri;
Button vid;

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == -1 && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        this.uri = data.getData();
        this.file.setText(this.uri.getPath());
    }
}

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_upload);
    this.firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    this.firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    this.storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    this.prob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProblem_upload);
    this.file = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewFile_upload);
    this.img = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage_upload);
    this.vid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVideo_Upload);
    this.upld = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload_upload);
    this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_upload);
    this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
            Upload.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    this.vid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    try {
        this.upld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (prob.getText().toString().isEmpty() || file.getText().toString().equals("No file selected")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please write your problem and upload a file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                upload_file_also(uri);
                USER_ID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                TIME_ID = System.currentTimeMillis();
                firestore.collection("users").document(USER_ID).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        NAME = documentSnapshot.getString("NAME_");
                        PHONE = documentSnapshot.getString("PHONE_");
                    }
                });
                NAME = NAME == null ? "null" : NAME;
                PHONE = PHONE == null ? "null" : PHONE;
                if (!NAME.equals("null") && !PHONE.equals("null")) {
                    CollectionReference collection = firestore.collection("problems");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append("ProbID-");
                    sb.append(TIME_ID);
                    DocumentReference documentReference = collection.document(String.valueOf(sb.toString()));
                    Map<String, Object> user_problems = new HashMap<>();
                    user_problems.put("DESCRIPTION_problems", prob.getText().toString());
                    user_problems.put("NAME_problems", NAME);
                    user_problems.put("PHONE_problems", PHONE);
                    user_problems.put("MEDIA_problems", Upload.this.MEDIA_url);
                    documentReference.set(user_problems).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(Upload.this.getApplicationContext(), "Successfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Upload.this.startActivity(new Intent(Upload.this.getApplicationContext(), Dash_farmer.class));
                            Upload.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public void upload_file_also(Uri fileUri) {
    StorageReference storageReference2 = this.storageReference;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("ProbID-");
    sb.append(this.TIME_ID);
    final StorageReference sr = storageReference2.child(String.valueOf(sb.toString()));
    sr.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<TaskSnapshot>) new OnSuccessListener<TaskSnapshot>() {
        public void onSuccess(TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            sr.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Upload.this.MEDIA_url = uri.toString();
                    Upload.this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Upload.this.upld.setText("TAP AGAIN TO UPLOAD MEDIA");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

I'm unable to find why this isn't working. Please put a light on where this is going wrong.

Comment: Please provide the error message so we can know exactly what is wrong. Also, in the code that you shared there's no object `media_problem`.